# How do I sort divs alphabetically, while keeping the divs' forms?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to sort my *divs* alphabetically, based on their titles in `h4`, by clicking on the button. But what happens is the following: all the `h4` titles, collected from all the divs, get squeezed (though alphabetically) inside the first div, leaving all the other divs without title and unsorted. I got the script from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_list.asp), and the other scripts are from irrelevant parts, however still (somehow) needed - I don't know much about javascript yet. Thus, any idea on how to make the divs be sorted based on their title in `h4`, while keeping the them whole?

```js
function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("id01");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("h4");
    // Loop through all list-items:
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      // start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item: */
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        /* if next item is alphabetically
        lower than current item, mark as a switch
        and break the loop: */
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done: */
      b[i].parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1], b[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
  
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.row {margin: 0px 0px 0 20.3vmin;}
/* Add padding BETWEEN each column */
.row, .row > .column {padding:0 1vmin 1vmin 1vmin;}
/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: none; /* Hide all elements by default */
}
.theimg{position:relative;display:block;height:24vmin;} 
.theimg img{position:relative;display:inline-block;height:100%;width:80%;} 
/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* Contentt */
.contentt {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1.2vmin;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  max-width:200px;
  height:43vmin;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden; 
}
h4{margin:0;}
/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sortList()">Sort</button>
<div class="row" id="id01">
  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Oliver Twist"></div>
      <h4>Oliver Twist</h4>
    </div>
  </div>    
    
    <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Steen der Wijzen"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Steen der Wijzen</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
    <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Geheime Kamer"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Geheime Kamer</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
    <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Gevangene van Azkaban"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Gevangene van Azkaban</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
    <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Vuurbeker"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Vuurbeker</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
    <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Orde van de Feniks"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Orde van de Feniks</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
  </div>
```

Comment: [`Node.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore): _"The `Node.insertBefore()` method inserts a node before a reference node as a child of a specified parent node."_ - `b[i]` and `b[i + 1]` are `<h4>` nodes.

Comment: @ggorlen What's _unusual_ on sorting a list of elements? It might not be the most elegant way but if it works...

Comment: @ggorlen Move existing nodes vs. create new ones. I definitely prefer the first option.

Comment: @Andreas, They are ''tags'' for the filtering system, but that system works just fine, so I thought it was irrelevant to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to target the correct nodes. You were targeting the `<h1>` nodes with `insertBefore`.  You just needed a couple extra `parentNode`s on there.

All I changed was this:
`b[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1].parentNode.parentNode, b[i].parentNode.parentNode);`

```js
function sortList() {
  var list, i, switching, b, shouldSwitch;
  list = document.getElementById("id01");
  switching = true;
  /* Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done: */
  while (switching) {
    // start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    b = list.getElementsByTagName("h4");
    // Loop through all list-items:
    for (i = 0; i < (b.length - 1); i++) {
      // start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /* check if the next item should
      switch place with the current item: */
      if (b[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b[i + 1].innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        /* if next item is alphabetically
        lower than current item, mark as a switch
        and break the loop: */
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /* If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark the switch as done: */
      b[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(b[i + 1].parentNode.parentNode, b[i].parentNode.parentNode);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}

filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  margin: 0px 0px 0 20.3vmin;
}


/* Add padding BETWEEN each column */

.row,
.row>.column {
  padding: 0 1vmin 1vmin 1vmin;
}


/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: none;
  /* Hide all elements by default */
}

.theimg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 24vmin;
}

.theimg img {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
}


/* Clear floats after rows */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Contentt */

.contentt {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1.2vmin;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 43vmin;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}


/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sortList()">Sort</button>
<div class="row" id="id01">

  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Oliver Twist"></div>
      <h4>Oliver Twist</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Steen der Wijzen"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Steen der Wijzen</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Geheime Kamer"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Geheime Kamer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Gevangene van Azkaban"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Gevangene van Azkaban</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Vuurbeker"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Vuurbeker</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Orde van de Feniks"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Orde van de Feniks</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do the sorting yourself. If you get the `.column`s and convert them into an actual array (with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or [`[].slice.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like_objects)) you can use [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

[`Node.prototype.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) is an option but you can also first sort all the nodes and then just "append" them to the container with [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). With this you don't need any reference node like with [`.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

Example (where I've removed everything that's not directly related to the sorting):

```js
function sortList() {
  var container = document.querySelector("#id01"),
      columns = container.querySelectorAll(".column");
      
  if (columns.length) {
    columns = Array.from(columns); // or [].slice.apply(columns) if Array.from() is not available
    
    columns.sort(function(leftColumn, rightColumn) {
      var leftTitle = leftColumn.querySelector("h4").textContent;
      var rightTitle = rightColumn.querySelector("h4").textContent;
      
      return leftTitle.localeCompare(rightTitle);
    });
    
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
      container.appendChild(column);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.row { margin: 0px 0px 0 20.3vmin; }
.row, .row>.column { padding: 0 1vmin 1vmin 1vmin; }
.column { float: left; width: 33.33%; }
.theimg img { display: none }
```

```html
<button onclick="sortList()">Sort</button>
<div class="row" id="id01">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Oliver Twist"></div>
      <h4>Oliver Twist</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Steen der Wijzen"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Steen der Wijzen</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Geheime Kamer"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Geheime Kamer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Gevangene van Azkaban"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Gevangene van Azkaban</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Vuurbeker"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Vuurbeker</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Orde van de Feniks"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Orde van de Feniks</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution to this question. It is a full rewrite with comments detailing every step.

> in this example I used the following functions en methods
>
> - [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
> - [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
> - [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
> - [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
function sortList() {
  //lets redo this properly and make a lesson about it:
  
  //we want to sort based upon the table:
  //first we use element.querySelectorAll to get all elements with h4.
  //querySelectorAll allows us to select elements the same way we select elements in CSS. When found it return as nodelist containing the elements over which we can iterate.
  
  //use es6 constant | it defines a variable and locks it 
  const row = document.querySelector("div.row#id01"); //select the row: div.classname#id
  
  //select all h4-elements with querySelectorAll:
  const h4Elements = row.querySelectorAll("div.contentt > h4"); //use div.contentt as reference and select the childs (>) h4
  
  //iterate over all the h4 elements
  //this is the main sorting loop!
  //convert the nodelist to an array and sort them
  const sorted = Array.from(h4Elements).sort( function(a, b) 
    {
      //textContent references the text
      if(a.textContent < b.textContent) { return -1; }
      if(a.textContent > b.textContent) { return 1; }
      return 0;
    });
    
  sorted.forEach( function(element){
      //loop over the sorted array
      //append the parent div again to the row
      //use element.closest to find the parent div container
      row.appendChild(element.closest("div.column"));
  });
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.row {margin: 0px 0px 0 20.3vmin;}

.row, .row > .column {padding:0 1vmin 1vmin 1vmin;}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.theimg{position:relative;display:block;height:24vmin;} 
.theimg img{position:relative;display:inline-block;height:100%;width:80%;} 

/* Contentt */
.contentt {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1.2vmin;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  max-width:200px;
  height:43vmin;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden; 
}

h4{margin:0;}
```

```html
<button onclick="sortList()">Sort</button>
<div class="row" id="id01">
  
  <div class="column Oliver Twist Charles Dickens Engels">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Oliver Twist"></div>
      <h4>Oliver Twist</h4>
    </div>
  </div>    
    
    <div class="column Harry Potter en de Steen der Wijzen J. K. Rowling Nederlands fantasie">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Steen der Wijzen"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Steen der Wijzen</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
    <div class="column Harry Potter en de Geheime Kamer J. K. Rowling Nederlands fantasie">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Geheime Kamer"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Geheime Kamer</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
    <div class="column J. K. Rowling Harry Potter fantasie Nederlands">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Gevangene van Azkaban"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Gevangene van Azkaban</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
    <div class="column Harry Potter en de Vuurbeker J. K. Rowling Nederlands fantasie">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Vuurbeker"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Vuurbeker</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
    <div class="column Harry Potter en de Orde van de Feniks J. K. Rowling Nederlands fantasie">
    <div class="contentt">
      <div class=theimg><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="Harry Potter en de Orde van de Feniks"></div>
      <h4>Harry Potter en de Orde van de Feniks</h4>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Your method sorts the column divs, mine uses the h4. If I don't use `sorted` it won't work.